# How can I access properly the DOM within a function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a sample HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="myButton" title="test">Test</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

with the correspondent JS code:

```
window.onload = function_onload(); 

function function_onload () {
    var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
    myButton.addEventListener("click", function_onclick());
}

function function_onclick() {
    alert("Hello word");
}
```

I do not understand why the variable `myButton` is `null` in this case. Should I pass the `window.document` as parameter to the `function_onload`? I already tried this but it neither works.

Comment: remove `()` from `function_onclick()` also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of it, you're invoking the method immediately. I believe you want to do this instead:

```
window.onload = function_onload
```

Remember that the function object is invoked with the parentheses, which is what is happening in your case. So instead, just remove them so that you are referencing the function, rather than immediately calling it.

Also, as Deryck noted in the comments, you're doing the same thing with your "click" event listener in the body `function_onload` function. Same thing as before, remove the parentheses from `function_onclick` so that you pass the function itself, rather than invoking immediately.

```
myButton.addEventListener("click", function_onclick);
                                                  ^^
                                                  Remove parentheses here
```

Comment: dont forget his `function_onclick()`

Comment: Might as well contribute this as well while I'm at it.  http://jsfiddle.net/SfYq2/